# Why does @ViewChildren pick the template only for the first time?

Tags: angular, angular-components, viewchild

I am creating an app where I want to render the buttons inside a table using a component. So, I created a component where I'v kept the button template and am using `@ViewChildren` to get the template and `ViewContainerRef` to apply the component to the template. However, only the first row is getting set and not the other. I can't figure out the reason for this?
Here's what I'v been trying: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsxvbt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because you are using a single reference with `@ViewChild`, but you are inside an `ng-For` and so you have to manage a `QueryList` of `ViewContainerRef` with `@ViewChildren`.

Try to change your code as follow:

replace:

```
@ViewChild("dynamic", { static: false, read: ViewContainerRef }) ref;
@ViewChildren("dynamic") private button: QueryList<"dynamic">;
```

with:

```
@ViewChildren('dynamic', {read: ViewContainerRef}) public widgetTargets: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

so that we can have a *ref* to every children.

replace:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      HelloComponent
    );
    const ref = this.ref.createComponent(componentFactory);
    
  }
```

with:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const targets = this.widgetTargets.toArray();
    for (let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
        let target = targets[i];
        if(target) {
            let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
            let cmpRef: any = target.createComponent(componentFactory);
        }
    }
  }
```

so that we can cycle over our list of *refs* and create our component on the fly

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psyh9d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

All the best.

Comment: Well it works good when data is present when view is initialized but if there is a delay in getting the `dataItems` than there is a delay for rendering `*ngIf` block and as a result `@ViewChildren` is not able to get the template. Can you help in such a case?

Comment: probably you have just to subscribe to an observable source, btw please add a new question, all the best

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to inject a dynamic component with ComponentFactoryResolver. You can inject your component by using his tag name `<hello></hello>`. I updated your stackblitz with a working solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbbewn